# Format strings vs concatenation

Tags: python, string-formatting

I see many people using format strings like this:

```
root = "sample"
output = "output"
path = "{}/{}".format(root, output)
```

Instead of simply concatenating strings like this:

```
path = root + '/' + output
```

Do format strings have better performance or is this just for looks?

Comment: I would guess they have worse performance. But I still prefer format strings in non-performance-critical places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619384/python-string-formatting-vs-concatenation)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's just for the looks. You can see at one glance what the format is. Many of us like readability better than micro-optimization.

Let's see what IPython's `%timeit` says:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan  3 2019, 02:55:40)
IPython 5.8.0
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590T CPU @ 2.00GHz

In [1]: %timeit root = "sample"; output = "output"; path = "{}/{}".format(root, output)
The slowest run took 12.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 5: 223 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit root = "sample"; output = "output"; path = root + '/' + output
The slowest run took 13.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 5: 101 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit root = "sample"; output = "output"; path = "%s/%s" % (root, output)
The slowest run took 27.97 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 5: 155 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit root = "sample"; output = "output"; path = f"{root}/{output}"
The slowest run took 19.52 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 5: 77.8 ns per loop
```

Comment: Note that since Python 3.6, you can use path = "{root}/{output}" which is quite straightforward...

Comment: @comte you need an f in front of it, but yes.

Answer (score 39):

I agree that the formatting is mostly used for readability, but since the release of f-strings in 3.6, the tables have turned in terms of performance. It is also my opinion that the f-strings are more readable/maintainable since 1) they can be read left-right like most regular text and 2) the spacing-related disadvantages of concatenation are avoided since the variables are in-string.

Running this code:

```
from timeit import timeit

runs = 1000000


def print_results(time, start_string):
    print(f'{start_string}\n'
          f'Total: {time:.4f}s\n'
          f'Avg: {(time/runs)*1000000000:.4f}ns\n')


t1 = timeit('"%s, %s" % (greeting, loc)',
            setup='greeting="hello";loc="world"',
            number=runs)
t2 = timeit('f"{greeting}, {loc}"',
            setup='greeting="hello";loc="world"',
            number=runs)
t3 = timeit('greeting + ", " + loc',
            setup='greeting="hello";loc="world"',
            number=runs)
t4 = timeit('"{}, {}".format(greeting, loc)',
            setup='greeting="hello";loc="world"',
            number=runs)

print_results(t1, '% replacement')
print_results(t2, 'f strings')
print_results(t3, 'concatenation')
print_results(t4, '.format method')
```

yields this result on my machine:

```
% replacement
Total: 0.3044s
Avg: 304.3638ns

f strings
Total: 0.0991s
Avg: 99.0777ns

concatenation
Total: 0.1252s
Avg: 125.2442ns

.format method
Total: 0.3483s
Avg: 348.2690ns
```

A similar answer to a different question is given on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481442/2000793).

Comment: I think f string has all 3: readability, concise (or easy to write), and the most optimized. I'm curious what other developers think.

Answer (score 14):

As with most things, there will be a performance difference, but ask yourself "Does it really matter if this is ns faster?".  The `root + '/' output` method is quick and easy to type out.  But this can get hard to read real quick when you have multiple variables to print out

```
foo = "X = " + myX + " | Y = " + someY + " Z = " + Z.toString()
```

vs

```
foo = "X = {} | Y= {} | Z = {}".format(myX, someY, Z.toString())
```

Which is easier to understand what is going on? Unless you *really* need to eak out performance, chose the way that will be easiest for people to read and understand

Answer (score 13):

It's not just for "looks", or for powerful lexical type conversions; it's also a must for internationalisation.

You can swap out the format string depending on what language is selected.

With a long line of string concatenations baked into the source code, this becomes effectively impossible to do properly.

Answer (score 10):

As of Python 3.6 you can do [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) by prepending `f` to the string:

```
foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"
path = f"{foo}/{bar}"
```

Answer (score 9):

String format is free of data type while binding data. While in concatenation we have to type cast or convert the data accordingly.

For example:

```
a = 10
b = "foo"
c = str(a) + " " + b
print c
> 10 foo
```

It could be done via string formatting as:

```
a = 10
b = "foo"
c = "{} {}".format(a, b)
print c
> 10 foo
```

Such that with-in placeholders `{} {}`, we assume two things to come further i.e., in this case, are `a` and `b`.

Comment: This is the reason I would use `.format`,  it avoids errors like `Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Comment: @Bert Sometimes that's a disadvantage - you may want a `TypeError` to propagate from the concatenation. So if using `.format` instead you would then have to add some additional type checking beforehand. So I think it's best to consider it on a case-by-case basis. I use both methods probably an equal amount.

Answer (score 3):

It's for looks and the maintaining of the code. It's really easier to edit your code if you used format. Also when you use + you may miss the details like spaces. Use format for your and possible maintainers' good.