# Why use f-strings or string format instead of just + for concatenation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation, f-string

I'm trying to actually learn python and use it for more than quick / dirty one-off scripts, and am wondering why is it best practice (or, is it even considered best practice) to use f-strings or string format instead of just using '+' for concatenation?

For example...

```
some_file_name = "abcd"
file_name = some_file_name + ".yaml"
file_name = f"{some_file_name}.yaml"
file_name = "{}.yaml".format(some_file_name)
```

What is the best practice here? Why not just use '+' to concatenate the variable and the string?

Comment: if `some_file_name` isn't a string, the f string or format method are easier to use.

Comment: `+` is a lot more variable in how it behaves across types, and offers far less control. The case where you're just formatting things as a string is the simple case, but f-strings or `format()` allow for lots of detailed controls -- padding, format conversion, etc. And you get errors if you pass a type that needs to have `str()` called it on it before it can be added to a string, *unless* you use a formatting mechanism that does that for you.

Comment: This link may help https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36

Comment: ...so, if you get in the habit of using `+`, sometimes it'll work for you and sometimes it won't, but if you get in the habit of f-strings, it'll pretty much always be flexible enough that you can make it do what you want.

Comment: Anybody sure if `file_name = some_file_name + ".yaml"` will create a throwaway `".yaml"` string before concatting? That would be a minor drawback

Comment: Also, `'{}-{}.yaml'.format(s1, s2)` and `f'{s1}-{s2}.yaml'` are more efficient than `s1 + "-" + s2 + ".yaml"`, which creates multiple temporary `str` objects as each `+` is evaluated.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722105/format-strings-vs-concatenation