# Concentrate two int to one decimal

Tags: python

What's the fastest way to concentrate two int into one decimal.

eg.

```
a=100
b=10
```

to get = 100.10

Thanks.

Comment: what should be the answer if `a=100` and `b=1`? `100.01` or `100.1`?

Answer (score 2):

Convert them into strings and then add them and again convert them

```
c = float(str(a) + '.'  + str(b))
```

Output:

```
100.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming python >= 3.6:

```
a = 100
b = 10

# if you want a string
c = f'{a}.{b}' 

# if you want a float
d = float(f'{a}.{b}')
```

It should be a little bit faster than string concatenation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38722105/11501222).

Answer (score 0):

Play with string concatenation

```py
y = float(str(a) + "." + str(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use string concatenation you can do the following:

```py
from math import log10, floor, pow

c = a + (b/(pow(10, floor(log10(b) + 1))))
```

Not sure if it is any more efficient. You can also import from numpy or import all of either numpy or math:

```py
import numpy

c = a + (b / (numpy.power(10, numpy.floor(numpy.log10(b) + 1))))
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough (for me at least), this is actually more efficient. Checked with `timeit` and was faster than the simple string concatenation. Less readable that's for sure...

Comment: @Tomerikoo FYI there is no difference between floor(...)+1 and floor(...+1) except in the very unusal edge case where the result of ... is so large that adding 1 would cause an overflow which if I'm not mistaken is around 2^1023, which is roughly 9*10^308, not really relevant in most situations

Comment: Python ints are not limited to `2^1024`. And actually it might be the same as `ceil(...)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo pow returns a float which is limited below 2^1024.As for ceil being the same, just try it. It will work fine for b=123 but it will fail for b=100.

Comment: @Tomerikoo After further reflection I suppose adding the 1 to the integer might be faster than adding it to the float though. Then again, maybe not

Comment: Oh I see now your point with `b=100`! Interesting. And you're right about the overflow, we are dealing with floats... Anyway, I found it interesting that this was actually faster than the obvious string concat