# Optimized summing beween ints and strs

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
print("ax^2 + bx + c = d what is your values for them? ")
a = int(input(">a = "))
b = int(input(">b = "))
c = int(input(">c = "))
d = int(input(">d = "))

given_parabola = str(a) + "x^2 + " + str(b) + "x + " + (str(c)) + " = " + str(d)
```

Is there any other way that I can merge integer variables with strings?

Comment: Not sure I understand you question but could you provide the value of all the variables and maybe an expected output?

Comment: Using a format string, perhaps?

Comment: Like `f"{a}x^2 + {b}x + {c} = {d}"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid concatenating multiple strings using the format string python proposed.

Using [`Format strings vs concatenation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722105/format-strings-vs-concatenation#answers) to do a list of more performant to less performant

- `f-string` as `f"{a}x^2 + {b}x + {c} = {d}"`
- `"%sx^2 + %sx + %s = %s" % (a,b,c,d)`
- `"{}x^2 + {}x + {} = {}".format(a,b,c,d)`

Answer (score 3):

The "best" approach really depends on what you're trying to do.

#### 1. Concatenating lists with variable number of items (numbers and strings)

If you simply want to form a string from numbers and strings, I would first create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) with generator expression and then join the strings with the `join()` method.

```py
In [1]: a = [2, 'a', 3, 'x', 'foo', 8, 55]

In [2]: g = (str(x) for x in a)

In [3]: ' '.join(g)
Out[3]: '2 a 3 x foo 8 55'
```

**Pluses**

- Can be used to concatenate any amount of strings and numbers, which can be in any order

**Minuses**

- Probably not the *most* speed optimized, if you *know more* about the variables you are going to concatenate

#### 2. Literal String interpolation

If you know what amount of numeric variables you want to concatenate with what strings, the problem is called [*string interpolation*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

In Python 3.6+ you can use so-called f-strings to form string using a string template and a fixed number of variables. For example:

```py
In [1]: a, b, c, d = 3, 2, 1, 5

In [2]: f"{a}x^2 + {b}x + {c} = {d}"
Out[2]: '3x^2 + 2x + 1 = 5'
```

**Pluses**

- Probably the most speed optimized way to create a string from a template.

**Minuses**

- This is not a general approach to "sum"/concatenate any amount of strings and numbers.

#### 3. Using sympy for expression generation

Since your problem looks like being very specific: You want to create string from mathematical formula, you might want to look at [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

**Installation**

```
pip install sympy
```

**Simple example**

```py
In [1]: from sympy import symbols, Eq, mathematica_code

In [2]: x, a, b, c, d = symbols('x a b c d')

In [3]: expr = Eq(a*(x**2) + b*x + c, d)

In [4]: var_dict = dict(a=3, b=2, c=1, d=5)

In [5]: expr_with_numbers = expr.subs(var_dict)

In [6]: mathematica_code(expr_with_numbers).replace('==', '=')
Out[6]: '3*x^2 + 2*x + 1 = 5'
```

you can also solve for the expression easily:

```py
In [7]: solve(expr_with_numbers, x)
Out[7]: [-1/3 + sqrt(13)/3, -sqrt(13)/3 - 1/3]
```

and you can print any kind of equation. For example

```py
In [1]: from sympy import symbols, Eq, mathematica_code, sqrt, pretty, solve

In [2]: expr = Eq(a*(x**2)/(sqrt(x-c)), d)

In [3]: var_dict = dict(a=3, b=2, c=1, d=5)

In [4]: expr_with_numbers = expr.subs(var_dict)

In [5]: print(pretty(expr_with_numbers, use_unicode=False))
      2
   3*x
--------- = 5
  _______
\/ x - 1
```

**Pros**

- Useful, if you want to create complex mathematical expressions
- Can also output pretty multiline output or even LaTeX output.
- Can be useful if you want to actually *solve* the equation, too

**Cons**

- Not speed-optimized for simple string formation.

Comment: I can't imagine this approach would be very performant even compared to regular concatenation. It also won't produce the results OP was specifically looking for as-is.

Comment: I guess your comment is regarding to the first option. Answering to new python questions is always a speed game, hence I was updating the answer one bit at a time. The answer has been updated to have different options for different use cases (all with their own pros and cons)

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest [string interpolation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation)?

```py
given_parabola = "%sx^2 + %sx + %s = %s" % (a, b, c, d)
```

## Or

```py
given_parabola = f"{a}x^2 + {b}x + {c} = {d}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hopefully, this is what you mean:

```py
# This way the integer 10 will convert to a string automatically. Works in Print as well!
x = 10
y = "lemons"
z = "In the basket are %s %s" % (x, y)
print(z)
```

Output:

> In the basket are 10 lemons