# Why we use format string not normal string in Python

Tags: python, string, format

I am now studying Python from scratch and I am confused about one point that has been mentioned in the Python book I am reading now. The program wants to print out the full name with first name and last name.
The example code from the book is below:

```
first_name = "ada"
last_name = "lovelace"
full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
message = f"Hello, {full_name.title}"
print(message)
```

I know that in the third line, the f"" means to format a string in Python 3.11. However, I am curious about why should I use a format string here but not a normal string. I mean if I rewrite the third line and the fourth line as below, I think it will provide the same results.

```
# full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
# message = f"Hello, {full_name.title}"
message = "Hello, " + full_name
```

So, I am curious about is there anything special about the format string? Or for the simplicity and elegance of my program, I should always use format string for long and complex string output?

Thanks for any explanation!

Comment: You need a different book. That code is broken

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722105/format-strings-vs-concatenation

Comment: [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) can act as template string so it's more simple (IMHO) to evaluate variables and control the output format (`:.3f` to get only 3 decimals or `:<10` to align string to left). Furthermore, I think each time you use `+` in a string you create a new string because str are immutable so it's not very efficient.

Comment: It's not so much that you should or shouldn't use one or the other, but for more complex examples it can be very powerful to use f-strings both in terms of maintaining readability but also simplicity of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you should to use a format strings due to:

```
something = "qwerty"
something_else = 123
```

and if you'll try to concatinate those variables with "+" operator, you'll get different types python exception

```
result = something + " " + something_else # there is exception
```

So, instead better use f string:

```
result = f"{something} + {something_else}" # works good
```

And at last good programmers uses f string instead "+" operator